# ¿Es correcta la palabra "pasándole"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos

Por ejemplo, la frase "Estuve toda la tarde pasándole mis apuntes por correo electrónico", ¿está bien escrita?

Básicamente me he encontrado que el corrector ortográfico hunspell no admite `pasándole` pero si `pasándolo`. Quería asegurarme antes de abrir un issue en https://github.com/sbosio/rla-es

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Para ese tipo de dudas puedes recurrir al diccionario de la rae. Buscas el verbo pasar y le das al botón de conjugación. Ahí encuentras «pasando» que es perfectamente válida. Por lo tanto «pasándole», «pasándola», «pasándoles» y «pasándolo» son también perfectamente válidas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perfectamente correcta. No es más que el gerundio *pasando* con el enclítico *le*, que funciona como objeto indirecto.

Si suponemos que la persona a quien pasas tus apuntes se llama Marta, y sustituimos el pronombre, nos quedaría *Estuve toda la tarde pasando a Marta mis apuntes por correo electrónico*; aquí queda más claro que *a Marta* es el objeto indirecto y, por tanto, es correcto sustituirlo por *le*.

Hay que tener en cuenta que los correctores ortográficos no siempre incluyen todas las posibles combinaciones de verbos con enclíticos, por lo que no son del todo fiables en estos casos.